# How do I give Apache Access to folders on MAC OSx?

Tags: php, apache, macos

I'm real new to Mac and Apache. I my development machine my website cannot access any files under the web roots /images or /css folders.

The apache log gives the following error:

**(13)Permission denied: file permissions deny server access:**

The site is hosted up under the 'Sites' folder. I checked in 'Get Info' on this folder and it seems that 'Everyone' has read access. What gives?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry Im new to OSX but when I look in Get Info I see three accounts and their privileges. They are userName (Me), staff, everyone. My account had read/write access and the other two have read. I don't see any mention of groups or ownership here.

Comment: That generally means the owner is userName (Me) and the group is staff, but Get Info doesn't always display the full permissions.  To get full details, open Terminal and run the command `ls -lea /path/to/folder` (if you aren't sure how to enter the path, you can drag-and-drop it from the Finder and it'll paste in the path for you).

Comment: Thanks for the info.. it appears that both folders are owned by my user and the group is indeed 'staff'.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x are the privileges for both folders?

Comment: Does that mean I need add www to staff? I believe that is the default account that apache uses right?

Comment: The since listed permissions include read access for everyone, and there doesn't appear to be an access control list (which could override that), the _www user *should* have access unless it's being denied someplace else.  Is the folder inside a parent (or grandparent or...) folder that _www doesn't have access to?  Also, does _www have read access to the files inside the images and css folders?

Comment: Why not just add _www to the staff group? Problem for me is that my /etc/group file doesn't even list staff so I'm lost.

Answer (score 26):

The problem is that Apache runs with a user different to the user owner of files, and the Apache's user doesn't have read/write/execute permissions. In my case the user was `_www` and is member of the `_www` group.

I solved this issue changing the group of the files to the `_www`:

1. Look for the apache's user and group. I used this php script:

   ```
   <?php
   echo exec('whoami') . '<br>';
   echo exec('groups') . '<br>';
   ?>
   ```
2. Login with the user owner of the files.
3. Add the user owner of files to the `_www` group.

   ```
   $ sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a userOwnerOfFiles -t user _www
   ```
4. Change the group of files needed to `_www`

   ```
   $ chgrp -R _www path/containing/files
   ```
5. Change file permissions for the group

   ```
   $ chmod -R g+rwx path/containing/files
   ```

Comment: step 3: "Record was not found."

Comment: Michael, did you replace 'userOwnerOfFiles' with the actual owner of the files?

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative way of solving this is using extended attributes in MacOSX

chmod +a "_www allow list,read,search,readattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit" /path/to/document_root

Answer (score 3):

I've found 2 things did the trick for me (I was specifically trying to get apache to have access to the Downloads folder):

1. In System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy scroll to Full Disk Access on the left, make sure you unlock at bottom, and then click the + to add an app. Navigate to /usr/sbin and find the executable `httpd` and add that, making sure it has full disk access enabled. Re-lock the preferences
2. Right click the particular folder in Finder and choose Get Info, then under Sharing & Permissions, allow access for the "everyone" user (or if you are trying to be more security conscious, perhaps only allow for "_www" user - but I did not test this).

That solved it for me

Answer (score 2):

This was a tough one for me today. It turned out that I needed to give permissions to the web server to the entire directory tree all the way up to the doc root.

It came up for me today because I'm using a virtual host and storing the files pretty far up a tree in my user directory.

I did not want to recursively change all the thousands of files in my Documents directory so I just chmod ed each folder in the path. In my home directory:

```
$ chmod 755 Documents
$ chmod 755 Documents/projects
$ chmod 755 Documents/projects/dev
$ chmod 755 Documents/projects/dev/someglamorousclientname/
$ chmod 755 Documents/projects/dev/someglamorousclientname/docroot
```

Answer (score 2):

This method is safe & fast to test, and easy to switch back if it's not working (it won't mess up things even more, which is ofter a problem when fixing these kind of issues:

1. Locate `httpd.conf` (you can do it with `httpd -V` in terminal)
2. Open this file in Brackets or any text editor
3. In this file, find:
   `User _www`
   `Group _www`
4. Change it to
   `User {your username}`
   `Group staff`

**Maybe you will have to add something else to your `User` and `Group`:**

1. In this `httpd.conf` file, you can also find a path to your webserver, just search for `DocumentRoot`. Copy this path, and navigate to it in terminal with `cd` command, for example:
    `cd /Library/WebServer/Documents`
2. When you are in, do a `ls -l`. This will give you info about webroot folder ownership. Adjust your `User` and `Group` in the `httpd.conf` regarding this
3. You can also enter the webroot folder and check the sites ownerships as well with `ls -l`, and update `httpd.conf` regarding that.

If this is not working, don't forget to switch back to:
`User _www`
`Group _www`