# ImageMagick not working on Snow Leopard server

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd, osx-snow-leopard

I'm trying to integrate imageMagick onto my server but I'm having a hard time to get it to work with any php commands. I think it may be because of the previous server configurations I did and now I'm not sure what to do as this is my first time using a Snow Leopard Server.

Here is the line of code I am attempting to process:

```
$sCommand="/opt/local/bin/convert -geometry ".$neededWidth."x".$neededHeight." \"" .$image_path."\" \"".$newFile."\" ";
$vvv=exec( $sCommand, $exec_output, $exec_retval );
```

Here is a little historic on my last server updates just in case it may be of some relevance:

> after noticing that the captcha images were not working I did some research on how to enable freetype. After install XCode, I recompiled PHP a few times with libPNG, libPNG (I say a few times because some of the instations failed at some times). I finally got it working and here is the results : http://tradeport.on.ca/phpinfo.php my GD section has everything I need.
>
> I've attempted to integrate imageMagick using the files and instructions on their site, that didn't work. I tried installing homebrew and that just seems to complicate things.
>
> Now I think I've got my wires crossed and think that there may be left over configurations of MacPorts, Homebrew and also some configurations from the native server admin application

I'm not expecting someone to cure this server but any information would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: In a terminal on the server, does this work: `/opt/local/bin/convert -version`

Comment: Yes it does. it returns `/opt/local/bin/convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.9-0 2012-09-18 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP OpenCL  `

Comment: Good, does it have permission to run as whatever user the web server runs as?

Comment: I'm not sure. I vaguely recolect doing some sudo work but is there a way to be sure?

Comment: Well if the server is running, you can see it's user, the command `ps` shows details of running processes, can't remember on Darwin if the flags are different, but usually `ps aux` will show all processes.  Once you know the user, you can check the convert executable permissions with `ls -l /opt/local/bin/convert`.

Comment: Once you know the user, you can check the convert executable permissions with ls -l /opt/local/bin/convert.

I'm not sure how to find the user itself (this is my first time doing maintenance on a mac server). I did the `ps` and the `ps aux` but I don't know what I'm looking for in the list of processes.

Comment: You would be looking for the process that is running the webserver, `apache` perhaps?  The information you would want, would be under the user column.  Usually there is a parent process and a lot of child processes for apache, the usual user for it is `nobody`.

Comment: Could well be the wrong tree anyway - I assume you have looked at the output of that `exec()` command in `$exec_output`?

Comment: It simply shows up as an empty array.

Comment: Do you get anything in `$exec_retval`?  Presumably the paths exist for `$image_path` and `$newFile`?

Comment: Here are the values returned

`$exect_retval = 1
$image_path = /private/var/tmp/phplCgD3X
$newfile = /Library/WebServer/Documents/tradeport.swslive.com/httpdocs/dat/slideshow/13.jpg`

Comment: The exit code of 1 usually means something went wrong.  You're probably not getting the error output, add `2>&1` as an additional parameter right at the end of the command, that redirects `stderr` to `stdout`.

Comment: I think you were on to something about the permisions. here is the output result: `convert: unable to open image  /Library/WebServer/Documents/tradeport.swslive.com/httpdocs/dat/slideshow/14.jpg': Permission denied @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2642`

Comment: Aye, check the permissions of that file, the user and the group.  If the webserver (apache) is running as `nobody`, then other (world) access is needed, probably to the entire directory.  If you have uploaded those files, they probably do not have sufficient permissions.

Comment: And that was the issue indeed. I'm posting the answer. Thank you Again for all your help Orbling.

Comment: No problem, glad it is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting permissions correctly was the answer to this issue. Thanks to Orblings guidance and following careful instructions on how to set permissions for apache on this page :

[How do I give Apache Access to folders on MAC OSx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079783/how-do-i-give-apache-access-to-folders-on-mac-osx)

my imageMagick functions were operational.