# How to give Apache access to external drive on MacOS Catalina onwards

Tags: macos, apache, macos-big-sur

On my new Big Sur Mac, I put the Apache document root on an external drive.

When I access it, the log showed no permissions: ***http://localhost/***

I tried what worked for another user: ***sudo chmod -R _www mydirectory***

I still get the error:

> ***file permissions deny server access: /Volumes/SSD1/Sites/index.html***

Also, an ***ls*** doesn't show the chmod working:

```
/Volumes/SSD1$ sudo chgrp -R _www Sites
/Volumes/SSD1$ ls -ld Sites Sites/index.html
drwxr-xr-x  19 John  staff  608 Feb 24 01:13 Sites
-r--r--r--   1 John  staff  833 Feb 24 01:13 Sites/index.html
/Volumes/SSD1$
```

Note that if I put that same directory tree under my home directory, it works (with corresponding changes to ***httpd.conf***, of course.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it. It took two tricks - one MacOS, and one Apache:

1. A getinfo on the drive showed that "**Ignore ownership on this volume**" was set. I fixed that. Note - this is on the very bottom of the Info dialog.
2. As mentioned in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9926627/1778316) to another question - I changed the group (using the shell in terminal) on everything in my directory to **_www**:

   **chgrp -R _www Sites**

Comment: This is good, as far as it goes. But you should also do the following: sudo chmod -R g+t Sites (or "find Sites -type d -exec sudo chmod g+t {} \;". chmod g+t for a directory will cause the GROUP owner of all files created in the directory to be assigned to the same group as the directory. It will not impact the user ownership in any way, and will not change ownership of any existing files/folders.